# How to convert / round a double value to int or String in flutter dart

Tags: flutter, dart

here is a double value

```
final dblValue = 25.5;
```

and I want this number as this `int` or `string`.
I tried the `replaceAll` function to remove the value after the `.`, but that didn't work too, I just need the number only without. value. how do I do that in dart

Comment: Does [`double.round`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/double/round.html) not do what you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [.floor()](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.17.1/dart-core/num/floor.html) method which goes to the int value without the decimal points. For a formal definition:

> The greatest integer no greater than this number.

```
final d = 25.9;
final d2 = 25.1;


int i = d.floor(); // i = 25
int i2 = d2.floor(); // i2 = 25
```

If you then want it as a string you can use the .toString() method on the int you just did.

Answer (score 0):

To convert it to a string use

```
dblValue.toString();
```

To round it use

```
dblValue.round();
```

Or

```
dblValue.toInt();
```

And to floor the value use

```
dblValue.floor();
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use the `.floor()` method to round up.

```
final dblValue = 25.5;
int value = d.floor(); // value = 25
```